# How to fix this error in Django, "Cannot assign must be an instance."

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I need help fixing this weird error please. I have an application whereby a teacher can add assignment, the student can then submit assignment and then the teacher can grade it. Right now, every other functionalities works perfectly well except when grading the result.

**Note**: "STUDENT 1" is the user whose assignment is to be graded

I understand I am using a string instead of an integer for the foreign key field but how can i get that fixed. is there a way to convert the string to integer or how. I tried this method but it doesn't seems to work. I tried "Student_ID__student_ID" and course__Course_Name which was just going to enter the model and use the field which was a string type and then i believe it should match but i got this error instead "Grade_Student() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Student_ID__student_ID'" and then i changed the "Grade_Student(...)" to Grade_Student.objects.update_or_create(...) and then got this new error "IntegrityError at /en/grading_submit
NOT NULL constraint failed: schoolapp_grade_student.Student_ID_id" and then i tried fixing it by changing Grade_Student_data.save() to Grade_Student_data.save(commit=False) but it was still same error. Is there anymore information you need to help me please.

Error log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\FIVERR\Ayyub_SMS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\FIVERR\Ayyub_SMS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\FIVERR\Ayyub_SMS\sms\schoolapp\views.py", line 1948, in grading_submit
    Assignment_name=grade_field_assignment_name, Grade=grade_field, Out_Of_Grade=out_grade_filed)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\FIVERR\Ayyub_SMS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 483, in __init__
    _setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\FIVERR\Ayyub_SMS\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 220, in __set__
    self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,

Exception Type: ValueError at /en/grading_submit
Exception Value: Cannot assign "'STUDENT 1'": "Grade_Student.Student_ID" must be a "add_students_by_manager" instance.
```

models.py

```
class add_courses(models.Model):
    Course_Name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    Manager_Name = models.ForeignKey(Manager_login_information, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    student = models.ManyToManyField(add_students_by_manager, blank=True)

    # Start Habib
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    # End Habib

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Course_Name


class add_students_by_manager(models.Model):
    manager_ID = models.ForeignKey(Manager_login_information, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student_ID = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student_name

class Grade_Student(models.Model):
    Student_ID = models.ForeignKey(add_students_by_manager, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(add_courses, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Assignment_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Grade = models.IntegerField()
    Out_Of_Grade = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Student_ID) + " scored " + str(self.Grade) + " out of " + str(self.Out_Of_Grade) + " in " + str(self.course)
```

views.py

```
def grading_submit(request):
    if request.method=="POST":

        grade_field_stu_id = request.POST.get('grade_field_stu_id')
        grade_field_course_name = request.POST.get('grade_field_course_name')
        grade_field_assignment_name = request.POST.get('grade_field_assignment_name')
        grade_field = request.POST.get('grade_field')
        out_grade_filed = request.POST.get('out_grade_filed')

        print(grade_field, grade_field_stu_id, grade_field_course_name, grade_field_assignment_name, out_grade_filed)

        Grade_Student_data= Grade_Student(Student_ID=grade_field_stu_id, course=grade_field_course_name, 
            Assignment_name=grade_field_assignment_name, Grade=grade_field, Out_Of_Grade=out_grade_filed)

        Grade_Student_data.save()

        messages.success(request, _("You Successfully Grade a student!"))

        return redirect('assignment_page')
    else:
        return redirect('/')
```

grading_page.html

```
<form class="container pt-5" action="{% url 'grading_submit' %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Grade</label>
    <input name="grade_field" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
    <input name="grade_field_stu_id" value="{{stu_id_grade}}" type="hidden" class="form-control">
    <input name="grade_field_course_name" value="{{stu_course_grade}}" type="hidden" class="form-control">
    <input name="grade_field_assignment_name" value="{{stu_ass_name_grade}}" type="hidden" class="form-control">
    <input name="out_grade_filed" value="{{stu_total_grade}}" type="hidden" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are not passing correct instance or id.Instead of Student_ID try Student_ID_id like this:

```
Grade_Student_data= Grade_Student(Student_ID_id=grade_field_stu_id, course_id=grade_field_course_name, 
            Assignment_name=grade_field_assignment_name, Grade=grade_field, Out_Of_Grade=out_grade_filed)

Grade_Student_data.save()
```

where grade_field_stu_id will be an id in integer i.e: 1. Do the same for your course field as well.

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: I will test it out now. Thanks

Comment: I tried it like that but it would not work bcos, "grade_field_stu_id" is a string, but the Student_ID_id would require a integer. look at the grading_page.html and see how that is being gotten.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the issue by changing this:

```
Grade_Student_data= Grade_Student(Student_ID=grade_field_stu_id, course=grade_field_course_name, 
            Assignment_name=grade_field_assignment_name, Grade=grade_field, Out_Of_Grade=out_grade_filed)
```

to this:

```
Grade_Student_data = Grade_Student(Student_ID=add_students_by_manager.objects.get(student_ID=grade_field_stu_id), course=add_courses.objects.get(Course_Name=grade_field_course_name), Assignment_name=grade_field_assignment_name, Grade=grade_field, Out_Of_Grade=out_grade_filed)
```